# エラーの対処方法　Cannot resolve method

Tags: android, java

Android開発初心者です。
以下のコードで、画像のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
super(context, R.layout.top_listview, items);
```

の部分を修正すればいいのかと思うのですが、どのようにしたらいいのでしょうか？
お知恵を頂けますと幸いです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
public class TopListViewAdapter extends ArrayList<TopElement> implements ListAdapter {
    public TopListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TopElement> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.top_listview, items);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ArrayAdapter` のコンストラクタの呼び出しに似ていますが、その `super(...)` は何かを参考に書かれたものでしょうか？

Comment: 他のAdapterは、上記と同様な形で問題なく動いていたため、同じ形を取りました。
先ほど、何故か、publicを削除しclassから始めた所正常に動きました。（すみません理由は不明です。）

Comment: superってのは、スーパークラスの構造関数をコールするのじゃないですか？
java.util.ArrayListには、そういう関数がないですね？

Answer (score 1):

ドキュメントのコンストラクタを見る限り、LisAdapter でなく ArrayAdapter ではないでしょうか？

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html